# Clamp framerate in Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, directx

I have a simple loop

```
LARGE_INTEGER ticks_per_second;
::QueryPerformanceFrequency(&ticks_per_second);

MSG msg = { 0 };
while (true)
{
    if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
        exit(0);

    if (::PeekMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0U, 0U, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
        ::DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        continue;
    }

    static double last_time_s = 0;

    LARGE_INTEGER cur_time_li;
    ::QueryPerformanceCounter(&cur_time_li);
    double cur_time_s = (double)cur_time_li.QuadPart / (double)ticks_per_second.QuadPart;

    double diff_s = cur_time_s - last_time_s;
    double rate_s = 1 / 30.0f;

    uint32_t slept_ms = 0;
    if (diff_s < rate_s)
    {
        slept_ms = (uint32_t)((rate_s - diff_s) * 1000.0);
        ::Sleep(slept_ms);
    }

    update();

    ::printf("updated %f %u\n", diff_s, slept_ms);

    last_time_s = cur_time_s;
}
```

And want update() to be called 30 times per second, but not more often
With this code it goes wrong, in console I getting something like this:

```
updated 0.031747 1
updated 0.001997 31
updated 0.031912 1
updated 0.001931 31
updated 0.031442 1
updated 0.002084 31
```

Which is seems to be correct only for first update, second one called too fast, and I can't understand why
I understand that update, PeekMessageW and etc. also wasting time, but even if I create a while (true) loop and comment update() out, it's still printing similar result
I using DirectX 11 with vsync turned off for rendering (rendering inside update function):

```
g_pSwapChain->Present(0, 0);
```

How do I fix code to make update() stable called 30 times in one second?

Comment: You may find this interesting: [Fix Your Timestep!](https://www.gafferongames.com/post/fix_your_timestep/).

Comment: Not sure about it, I don't see author of article using Sleep at all, but I need it to reduce processor load

Comment: Look at `CreateWaitableTimer()`. `Sleep` is not that accurate.

Comment: You do not need to use sleep. Doing so will result in stuttering and input latency because doing `Sleep` will not align to your monitor refresh rate. If you want to limit frame rate, use VSync.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think casting to double is  good idea.I would run something like this:

```
static LARGE_INTEGER last_time_s = { 0 };

::QueryPerformanceCounter(&cur_time_li);
time_diff_microsec.QuadPart = cur_time_li.QuadPart  - last_time_s.QuadPart;
// To avoid precision lost, convert to seconds *before* dividing by ticks-per-second.
time_diff_microsec.QuadPart *= 1000000;
time_diff_microsec.QuadPart /= ticks_per_second.QuadPart;

double rate_s = 1 / 30.0f;
uint32_t slept_ms = 0;
if (time_diff_microsec.QuadPart >= rate_s)//    if (diff_s < rate_s)
{
  //  slept_ms = (uint32_t)(rate_s - time_diff_microsec.LowPart);// *1000.0);
  //  ::Sleep(slept_ms);
  //}

  //update();

  ::printf("updated %lld %u\n", time_diff_microsec.QuadPart, slept_ms);
}
last_time_s.QuadPart = time_diff_microsec.QuadPart/ 1000000;
```

}

Just brief "sketch". Not verified that calculations are correct though.